# What is right way for string concatenation in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I wrote some vim plugin, that correctly works with vim8, but when I try run it with neovim I get error about invalid expression in string:

```
let var = str_first .. str_second
```

When I change `..` to `.` all works fine, so I want to ask: string concatenation by `..` is right? Why vim support both operators `.` and `..`, but neovim support only `.`?

Comment: `:help expr-..`

Comment: BTW. Neovim also supports both operators (at least, current beta version).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `..` string concatenation operator was added to Vim fairly recently, as of [version 8.1.1114 from April 2019](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/0f248b006c2574abc00c9aa7886d8f33620eb822).

The documentation at [`:help expr-..`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-..) explains the rationale for adding it:

> For String concatenation `..` is preferred, since `.` is ambiguous, it is also used for Dict member access and floating point numbers.

This commit has [been ported to NeoVim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/bfc44a91acdfb968cb3d0d21effc4ea9cbcd09e1) in May  2019 and it's present in NeoVim v0.4.4, the latest release of NeoVim as of this writing.

If you care about compatibility with older versions, you might want to stick with using `.` as a string concatenation operator. It's still around and it's not really going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: Or printf, which I find easier

Comment: I'm still always using `.`: it works with every version of Vim I may still have to use.

Comment: And by ambiguous they mean... that a programmer can misunderstand what a piece of code does? Or that under some conditions a piece of code might do something different?

Comment: @x-yuri The ambiguities are unlikely to arise in real life (`a .. b` raises an error when `a` is a Dict and floating point only affects number literals), but it's still important because now when Vim sees `a.b` it can only decide what it is by checking if `a` is a Dict. Vim9script is trying to make the language faster, which typically involves some kind of bytecode compilation, and in that case knowing which case is which at compile time is important.